# SQL Insert Script Generator with Dependency Trackert

Tags: sql-server

Is there any free tool to generate SQL insert Script in order of dependency.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) can script your entire database data in the dependency order.

Comment: what's about linux/postgres/oracle?

Answer (score 0):

How about the Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing wizard? You can Google it for more info.

Randy